# Проблема при обработке событий ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании `ExpandableListView`. Вроде бы все понятно, но все же, как для новичка есть проблема.

Задача в следующем: есть разметка для Group - текстовая метка и кнопка. Когда список развернулся - должен меняться текст кнопки (данной группы).

Я делаю так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public final String GROUP_NAME = "groupName";
    public final String CHILD_NAME = "phoneName";
    public ListAdapter listAdapter;

    ExpandableListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        //*** заполнение коллекций групп и их списков пропустил в примере 

        layoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, layoutInflater, groupData, childData);

        listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lever_list);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        listView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int i) {
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



    }

/// МОЙ АДАПТЕР:


    public class ListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private MainActivity context;
        private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groups;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childs;


        public ListAdapter(MainActivity context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groups, ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childs) {
            this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
            this.context = context;
            this.groups = groups;
            this.childs = childs;

        }


        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
            return childs.get(i).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int i) {
            return groups.get(i).get(GROUP_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
            return childs.get(i).get(i1).get(CHILD_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, final boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item, null);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_item);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(getGroup(i)));
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_button);
        if(b){
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Expandable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }




        return view;
    }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view == null){
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_item);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(getChild(i, i1)));

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }


        }

    }
```

Изменении текста кнопки делаю при развертывании так:

```
listView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int i) {
                    Button button = (Button)(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item, null)).findViewById(R.id.parent_button);
                    button.setText("+");
                }
            });
```

Что я делаю не так? Прошу помочь разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в обработчике раскрытия группы не обращаетесь к элементу разметки группы, а создаёте `View` из разметки. Т.е. пытаетесь поменять текст на неотображаемой кнопке, вместо кнопки отображаемой на экране.

Вам нужно

1. В getGroupView менять надпись на кнопке в зависимости от значения второго аргумента метода (`boolean isExpanded`, у вас `b`)
2. Перерисовать адаптер вызовом `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` в onGroupExpand

Второе, возможно, и не понадобится.

Comment: спасибо, вам  за ответ!! 
Я раньше так делал (отредактировал в вопросе метод getGroupView),но проблема в том, что мне нужно чтоб кнопка работала только при открытой группе, а в данном варианте (уже так как я отредактировал) после закрытия группы, при нажатии на кнопку, она все равно работает, хотя уже не должна!

Comment: @Maybe_V, вам надо просто убрать слушатель нажатий в случае если `b` `false`. Добавьте `else { button.setOnClickListener(null); }`